# Efficient algorithm to count possible words for a keypad sequence, WITHOUT T9

Tags: algorithm

**disclaimer**: since there are some *similar* but not *equal* questions, please read with attention, I can find only references for keypad with T9, but no one without.

- Given a Phone Keypad with letters

2 - a,b,c

3 - d,e,f

... and so on

- Given a sequence of number digits, example 222

**Request**: Find how many possible words can be written **WITHOUT T9**

Example:

222 can be:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'C' (length=1)
  1 => string 'AB' (length=2)
  2 => string 'BA' (length=2)
  3 => string 'AAA' (length=3)
```

So, 4 possible solutions

2222 can be:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => string 'AC' (length=2)
  1 => string 'BB' (length=2)
  2 => string 'CA' (length=2)
  3 => string 'AAB' (length=3)
  4 => string 'ABA' (length=3)
  5 => string 'BAA' (length=3)
  6 => string 'AAAA' (length=4)
```

So, 7 possible solutions

**Requirements:**
- no backtracking/bruteforce approach
- must be efficient with long sequences (more than 1000 digits, less than 10 sec to execute)
- **there is no need to return all the possible words** but only their count

Please note: I'm not looking for the final algorithm, but indications on the possible approach

Thanks

Comment: I have written an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53373675/count-all-possible-strings-from-given-mobile-numeric-keypad-sequence/). See if this helps you.

Comment: Brilliant! I don't understand why the question was downvoted and your answer has no upvotes, but this is exactly what I was looking for. If you add your answer here I can accept/upvote :-)

Comment: Thanks :) I haven't heavily tested but it works as of now. I request you to test it before accepting.

Comment: Yes I tested it and I confirm that it does what I need. Very good :-)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**Algorithm/Intuition:**

- As it represents in the above image, for a single digit, there are 3-4 possibilities.
- If we press the same digit 2 or 3 or 4 times, we get different characters on the display.
- Like, if we press `2`

  - 1 time - `a`
  - 2 times - `b`
  - 3 times - `c`
- So, when we calculate/count the number of possible substrings, we need to add `subproblem(i-2),subproblem(i-3),subproblem(i-4)` values to our total count if it happens that `i = i-1 = i-2`.
- For example, let's take **222**. We will adopt a top-bottom approach.
- First **2** in **222** has only 1 possibility(which will be typing `a`).
- For second **2** in **222**, it can give us either `a` or it might be that `2` was pressed 2 times giving us a `b`. So, combinations can be `aa` and `b`.
- For third **2** in **222**, it can be `a` or `b`(if started from second `2`) or `c`.
- Hence, no. of combinations for each index `i` is sum of no. of matches from `i` till `i-3` or `i-4`, depending upon no. of characters each digit represents in the keypad.
- Note that if i<sup>th</sup> character matches with `i-1`, then we add `dp[i-2]` and not `dp[i-1]` since `i-1 till i` represents a single character (when pressed multiple times).

**Code:**

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class Solution{    
    public static int possibleStringCount(String s){
        int len = s.length();
        int[] dp = new int[len];
        dp[0] = 1;// possibility is 1 for a single character
        for(int i=1;i<len;++i){
            int possible_chars_length = numberOfRepresentedCharacters(s.charAt(i)-'0') - 1;// because current character itself counts as 1. 
            dp[i] = 0;
            for(int j=i;j>=0;j--){
                if(i - possible_chars_length > j) break;
                if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)){
                    if(j-1 > -1){
                        dp[i] += dp[j-1];
                    }else{
                        dp[i] += 1;// if there are no combinations before it, then it represents a single character
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return dp[len-1];
    }

    private static int numberOfRepresentedCharacters(int digit){
       if(digit == 7 || digit == 9) return 4;
        return 3;// it is assumed that digits are between 2-9 always
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tests = {
            "222","2233","23456789","54667877","5466","7777","22","7898989899","77779999"
        };

        for(String testcase : tests){
            out.println(testcase + " : " + possibleStringCount(testcase));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
222 : 4
2233 : 4
23456789 : 1
54667877 : 8
5466 : 2
7777 : 8
22 : 2
7898989899 : 26
77779999 : 64
```

Comment: You may have change the datatype of variables to avoid overflow since your length can be more than 1000 digits.